# Add value to existing array key in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following bibliography data in an array (note that fields are in random order - there are others fields as well):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            ['Pub_Name'] => Nature
            ['Volume'] => 6
            ['Pages'] => 215-217
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            ['Volume'] => 15
            ['Pages'] => 358-360
            ['Pub_Name'] => Science            
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            ['Pub_Name'] => PNAS
            ['Pages'] => 17-19            
            ['Volume'] => 22
        )
)
```

I want to "merge" those three fields into one, for example `['Pub_Name']=Nature, 6: 215-217`. I tried the following whitout success (I guess `$Record['Pub_Name']` is the incorrect sintax):

```
foreach ($MyArray as $Record) {
    foreach ($Record as $key => $values) {
        if ($key=="Volume") {$Volumen=", ".$values;} else {$Volumen="";}
        if ($key=="Pages") {$Paginas=": ".$values;} else {$Paginas="";}
    }

    //This is the line for which I want to know the sintax!!
    $Record['Pub_Name'].=$Volumen.$Paginas;
}
```

Comment: Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for two loops:

```
foreach ($MyArray as $Record) {
    $result[]['Pub_Name'] = "{$Record['Pub_Name']}, {$Record['Pages']}: {$Record['Volume']}";
}
```

Then you have the new `Pub_Name` entries in `$result`.

If you want to modify the original then reference `&` `$Record`:

```
foreach ($MyArray as &$Record) {
    $Record['Pub_Name'] = "{$Record['Pub_Name']}, {$Record['Pages']}: {$Record['Volume']}";
}
```

Or use the key and modify the original array:

```
foreach ($MyArray as $key => $Record) {
    $MyArray[$key]['Pub_Name'] = "{$Record['Pub_Name']}, {$Record['Pages']}: {$Record['Volume']}";
}
```

Comment: It worked, thanks! And please, what does `&` account for in your second option?

Comment: It's a reference that modifies the array when you modify `$Record`. Explained here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: thanks. The warning for unseting `$Record` of your link also helped me...

Answer (score 1):

[**PHP code demo**](https://eval.in/767705)

```
<?php
$array=Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            'Pub_Name' => "Nature",
            'Volume' => 6,
            'Pages' => "215-217"
        ),
    1 => Array
        (
            'Volume' => 15,
            'Pages' => "358-360",
            'Pub_Name' => "Science"            
        ),
    2 => Array
        (
            'Pub_Name' => 'PNAS',
            'Pages' => "17-19",          
            'Volume' => 22
        )
);
$result=array();
foreach ($array as $data)
{
    $result[]=array('Pub_Name'=>  $data['Pub_Name'].", ".$data["Volume"].": ".$data["Pages"]);

}
print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Pub_Name] => Nature, 6: 215-217
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Pub_Name] => Science, 15: 358-360
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Pub_Name] => PNAS, 22: 17-19
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
<?php
$input = [
    [
        'Pub_Name' => 'Nature',
        'Volume' => '6',
        'Pages' => '215-217'
    ],
    [
        'Volume' => '15',
        'Pages' => '358-30',
        'Pub_Name' => 'Science',
    ],
    [
        'Pub_Name' => 'PNAS',
        'Pages' => '17-19',
        'Volume' => '22'
    ]
];
$output = [];
array_walk($input, function ($entry) use (&$output) {
    $output[] = sprintf(
        '%s, %s: %s',
        $entry['Pub_Name'],
        $entry['Volume'],
        $entry['Pages']
    );
});
print_r($output);
```

The output of above code obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Nature, 6: 215-217
    [1] => Science, 15: 358-30
    [2] => PNAS, 22: 17-19
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_map`

```
$in = [
    0 => [
        'Pub_Name' => 'Nature',
        'Volume' => 6,
        'Pages' => '215-217'
    ],
    1 => [
        'Volume' => 15,
        'Pages' => '358-360',
        'Pub_Name' => 'Science',
    ],
    2 => [
        'Pub_Name' => 'PNAS',
        'Pages' => '17-19',
        'Volume' => 22
    ]
];

array_map(function ($item) {
    return $item['Pub_Name'] . ', ' . $item['Volume'] . ': ' . $item['Pages'];
}, $in);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to do this - but one of the more readable ways:

```
// create a copy of the original - so we aren't looping thru the same array we're updating
$updatedArray = $MyArray;

foreach ($MyArray as $index => $record) {
    $updatedArray[$index]['Pub_Name'] =
        $record['Pub_Name'].  
        ($record['Volume'] ? ', '.$record['Volume'] : ''). 
        ($record['Pages'] ? ': '.$record['Pages']:'');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear way in a single loop. Use sprintf() for easy formatting:

```
<?php
$src =[ ['Pub_Name' => 'Nature', 'Volume' => '6', 'Pages' => '215-217'],
        ['Volume' => '15', 'Pages' => '358-30', 'Pub_Name' => 'Science'],
        ['Pub_Name' => 'PNAS', 'Pages' => '17-19',  'Volume' => '22']
      ];

foreach ($src as $element) {
    $dest[] = sprintf("%s, %d: %s", 
       $element['Pub_Name'], 
       $element['Volume'], 
       $element['Pages']);
}

var_dump($dest);
?>
```

And you get:

```
    array(3) { 
[0]=> string(18) "Nature, 6: 215-217" 
[1]=> string(19) "Science, 15: 358-30" 
[2]=> string(15) "PNAS, 22: 17-19"
 }
```

Test it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2fd087bb2a34ecb4fd2ff5faec5f3320011675a4).

Comment: Thanks a lot. So many answers in minutes (I've been stuck with this for a long time). Sadly there can be only one accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

This should help:

```
$combined = [];
foreach($myArray as $pub) {
    $combined.push($pub['Pub_Name'] . ', ' . $pub['Volume'] . ': ' . $pub['Pages']);
}
```